# One NIC for AMT and another for the OS user?

Tags: amt

I have never worked with AMT, I would like to make sure the following scenario would be possible before I start to invest in a few Intel AMT machines.

Let's assume the server has two NICs and each NIC has a different internet connection. Would it be possible to use one NIC for Intel AMT and the other for the OS? And at the same time hide the NIC used for the Intel AMT management to the OS and the OS user?